# Streaming live from a pre recorded video via websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, streaming

Sorry for English, I am using a translator.

As the title itself already explains, need to create a live broadcast using localhost (apache server), and I thought I could use websockets for this transmission, the video for this transmission would be in the database (MySQL).

It is feasible to broadcast live via websocket how? 
Any code or link helps a lot, just to give me a way how to solve this problem 
Any help will be well received, thankful this already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27429/reprodu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-video-ao-vivo-usando-websocket, I guess?

Comment: This link is my question, could be doubled if there was a sufficiently satisfactory answer, therefore I'm asking again because I did not find material related to my problem, Jan Dvorak, you have any tips on how I can start?